# Shuffling an array with a set of rules and returning the value from the function

Tags: c++, arrays

I am relatively new to C++, I have only started learning it this year.
I am having trouble writing a little program to take in a text document and store it in an array. Then take that array and randomise the values in a certain way. It is for a rostering program to arrange the riders + horses into suitable positions.

What I am trying to attempt in this function (gen() ) is to copy the entry[num] to entry2[num2] . Where num is the amount of entries there are, and num2 is a randomly generated rand() number. I then wanted it to check if the new entry is atleast 15 positions more then the old entry (in this case.. so the rider of the horse can have a break before his next event)

so as you can guess .. this application doesnt work, im guessing there is an easier way?
How can I send the variables into this array, And how can I get this function to return the array back to my main .. im guessing via a pointer?

I have attached the whole code below.

```
/*   ________________________________________________________________________________
*    |   TITLE:     main.cpp                                                        |
*    |   AUTHOR:    Samuel Abbott (samuel.d.abbott@gmx.com)                         |
*    |   PURPOSE:   to take camp draft data in, randomise it with certain values,   |
*    |              and output the new roster as a text document                    |
*    |   DATE:      may 1, 2012                                                     |
*    |   LAST EDIT: may 3,2012                                                      |
*    |______________________________________________________________________________|
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h> //random number
#include <time.h> //random number
#include <fstream> //used for input / output of external files

using namespace std;
/*
*   TITLE: gen
*   PURPOSE: to randomise the entries , check to see if they are more then 15 units  apart, and return a pointer to the randomised array
*   string entry[] holds original values
*   int num [] holds number of entries
*/
sting gen(string entry[], int num)
{
   int count = 0;
   string entry2[num]; //randomised array

   /* initialize random seed: */
   srand(time(NULL));

   for (count =0; count < num)
   {
      num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
      entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array

      /* a series of if checks to make sure the entry is no less then 15 positions from the previous entry */
      if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-15])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-14])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-13])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-12])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-11])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-10])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-9])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-8])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-7])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-6])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-5])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-4])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-3])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-2])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else if (entry2[num2]=entry[num-1])
      {
         num2 = rand() % num; //generate random number
         entry[num] = entry2[num2]; //copy number from array to a random position in the next array
      }

      else
      {
         entry[num] = entry2[num2];
      }
   }

   string pointer* = entry2[]
   return pointer
}

/*
*   Title : Loading
*   Purpose: This function generates a loading animation. in other words. just a fancy     graphic.
*   HAS NO LOADING PURPOSE
*/

void loading()
{
   /* Declare loading variable, this variable is just the screen printout */
   string loading = "...";
   int time = 0;
   int loadtime = 10;

   /* print out loading animation */
   while (time != loadtime)
   {
      cout << loading;
      time++;
   }

}
void loading();

/*
*   Title: Main
*   Purpose: this is the main function for the randomisation program
*/
int main()
{
//declare all variables
   string fname = "";
   int count;

   string line;
   ifstream inputfile;
   char c;
   int num=0;


   /* introduction */
   cout << "Roster Randomisation Generator" << endl;
   /* Get input for roster name */
   cout << "Enter a name for the roster, such as 13022012coolah:"<<endl;
   cin>> fname;
   /* Begin generating roster */
   cout << "Roster Generation in progress." << endl;
   loading();
   /* get amount of lines in text file .. used to determine how many entries there are to     avoid printing blank spaces*/

   inputfile.open("output.txt");

   while (inputfile.good())
   {
      c = inputfile.get();

      if (c=='\n')
      {
         num++;
      }
   }

   inputfile.close();
   cout<<"Number of Entries counted is: "<<num<<endl;

   string entry[num];

   cout << "Grabbing entries from entry file..."<<endl;
   /* open text file*/
   inputfile.open("output.txt");

   /* read all data into the array entry[] */
   for (count = 0; count < num; count++)
   {
      getline(inputfile,line);  //Gets a single line from example.txt
      entry[count]=line;

      // inputfile >> entry[count];
   }

   inputfile.close();
   cout <<"Found the following entries: " <<endl;

   /* output captured entries*/
   for (count =0; count < num; count++)
   {
      cout <<entry[count] <<endl;
   }


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your following questions to the core problem.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to copy the array as-is, then use `std::random_shuffle` to randomize the copy.

Answer (score 2):

Two main issues right off the bat.

First, in the second line of your gen function you create an array with a size of a parameter.

`string entry2[num];`

You cannot do that in C++, normal "automatic"/stack arrays have to be created with a constant size.

Instead you should probably look into std::vector to store an array that can have variable sizes.

---

Second, your giant chain of if, else if statements seems unnecessary, not to mention buggy.

What happens when the new `num2` is wrong as well?

You should look into using a for loop to solve this problem with much less code.

---

A third issue is that you are using the wrong operator in that giant chain of if, else if statements.

You need to use `==`  for comparison. When you use assignment(`=`), it might seem to work, but it really just always returns true.

Comment: Not to mention the lack of `==` in those comparisons.

Comment: You should also add that using rand() with modulo is bad (it introduces a bias): http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx and http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html Of course this is avoided if you use something like Jerry Coffin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you are/want return a string* but your function definition is string gen(...). it would be good if you change that to string* gen(...).

secondly, you are doing an assaignment if(entry2[num2] = entry[num-12]). but i think you want to do a comparison. you do this with if(entry2[num2] == entry[num-12]). use double = for comparison and single = for assaignments.

thirdly, you are doing a lot of copy and paste, this could be encapsulated as loop.

```
for(int x = 15; x > 0; x--) 
{
    if(entry2[num2] == entry[num - x] 
    {
        num2 = rand() % num;
        entry[num] = entry[num - x];
        break; //maybe ?!
    }
}
```

fourthly, why are you creating a new number after you've already checked if the values are equal ? maybe you should keep your num2 instead of fault it after the compare.

fifthly, if i see it right, you are never increasing count. this will cause an infinite loop.

sixthly, you should use the new statement instead of the string[num] this won't work in c++.